# how can i plot_date according to continuing time-series data in pandas?

Tags: pandas, plot, time-series

i have below time-series dataframes and i wanna matplot 
using ax.plot_date() but i have some problem .. because 
in the graph 19:00~23:45, 00:00:00~02:00:00 is separated
displayed in the chart.. i wanna chart dispyed in continuing 
19:00~02:00 do anybody have solution? (Date/Time is multin-index)

```
               a
Date     2015-12-06
Time               
19:00:00      21.44
19:15:00      21.47
19:30:00      21.44
19:45:00      21.39
20:00:00      21.35
20:15:00      21.36
20:30:00      21.21
20:45:00      21.22
21:00:00      21.32
21:15:00      21.22
21:30:00      21.29
21:45:00      21.19
22:00:00      21.26
22:15:00      21.14
22:30:00      21.20
22:45:00      21.18
23:00:00      21.12
23:15:00      21.00
23:30:00      21.13
23:45:00      21.12
00:00:00      21.02
00:15:00      21.09
00:30:00      20.96
00:45:00      20.92
01:00:00      20.99
01:15:00      20.92
01:30:00      20.97
01:45:00      20.85
02:00:00      20.76
```

Comment: What about `ax = df.plot()`
`ax.set_xlim(xmin=time(19,0,0))` ?

Comment: i tried ... this only display 19:00~23:45 data.. i need display 19:00:00~02:00:00 chart

Comment: Not sure if some general solution is, but `ax.set_xlim(xmin=time(19,0,0), xmax=time(2,0,0))` working here

Comment: hmm.. still not working..

Comment: It is hard, maybe some matplotlib guy help you. I have no idea :(